# CouchDB bulk copy operation doesn't send back callback

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-nano

> I'm using nano db library (also try this with cloudant ant library)
>   for node js
>
> I have this sample code :

```
exports.insert = function (db_name, data, callback) {
    var db_name=db_name;   if(!db){   db = nano.use(db_name);   }   console.log(`try to make bulk copy to Couchdb`);   db.bulk(data, function (err, body) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(`data in db ${db_name} inserted successfully`);
      return callback(null, body);

    }
    console.log(`err ouccre ${err}`);
    return callback(err);

  }); }
```

> The "data" variable is an object that contain the 'docs' property and
>   'docs' contain array.
>
> I'ts always do the bulk work and put the docs array into my cloudnat
>   db , but
>
> Often **doesn't** return any callback (err / success)  to my node js
>   process
>
> and it stuck...
>
> Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you enable CORS?

Comment: Yes i choose "all domains (*)" in cors option

Comment: To completly enable Cors, you might get a look into [this](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb)